# Default persistence enforce set to true would anyway delete association table's lines

Tags: codefluent

The property defaultPersistenceEnforce is set to true at project level. We consider following example.

```
Meeting ----*> Contact <---- Case
```

When we have one contact referenced in the table `Case`, the call of stored procedure `Contact_Delete()` would fail as exepected.

But when there's no reference in table `Case` the execution of stored procedure `Contact_Delete()` would delete the lines inside association table `Meeting_Contacts_Contact`.

It doesn't make much sense since I would like to prevent such behavior. In particular, I didn't specify any cascade relationship for deletion.

I would like to make sure that tuples are not being erased in such tables, in particular when there are referenced.
How can I have the stored procedure `Contact_Delete()` to only delete Contact and don't consider references ?

Thanks for your answer,

Enclosed the model part and the definition of Contact_Delete stored procedure.

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="WcfServices.Model" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1" xmlns:cfom="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.model/2005/1" xmlns:cfsps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlpivotscript/2013/1" defaultPersistenceEnforce="true" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration produceViews="true" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.persistence" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.persistence\WcfServices.persistence.sqlproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update, DontRemove" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer name="Business Object Model (BOM)" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom">
    <cf:configuration compileWithVisualStudio="true" compile="false" codeDomProviderTypeName="CSharp" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.model" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.model\WcfServices.model.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update">
      <subProducer typeName="Ixcys.Producers.ServiceModelProducer.ServiceProducer, Ixcys.Producers.ServiceModelProducer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" compileWithVisualStudio="true" compile="false" codeDomProviderTypeName="CSharp" targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.proxy" silverlightTargetVersion="Unspecified" jsonOptions="EnableJson" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.web\WcfServices.web.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
    </cf:configuration>
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server Pivot Script" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlPivotScriptProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration targetDirectory="..\WcfServices.web" cfx:targetProject="..\WcfServices.web\WcfServices.web.csproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="Contact" namespace="Example.Model.Contact" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="ContactId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Name" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Case" namespace="Example.Model.Contact" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="CaseId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Description" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="InChargeContact" typeName="Example.Model.Contact.Contact" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Meeting" namespace="Example.Model.Contact" categoryPath="/WcfServices.Model">
    <cf:property name="MeetingId" key="true" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Date" typeName="date" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Label" persistenceEnforce="true" />
    <cf:property name="Contacts" typeName="Example.Model.Contact.ContactCollection" persistenceEnforce="true" />
  </cf:entity>
</cf:project>
```

The stored procedure Contact_Delete

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Contact_Delete]
(
 @Contact_ContactId [uniqueidentifier],
 @_rowVersion [rowversion]
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @error int, @rowcount int
DECLARE @tran bit; SELECT @tran = 0
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
 SELECT @tran = 1
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
END
DELETE FROM [Meeting_Contacts_Contact]
    WHERE ([Meeting_Contacts_Contact].[Contact_ContactId] = @Contact_ContactId)
SELECT @error = @@ERROR, @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
DELETE FROM [Contact]
    WHERE (([Contact].[Contact_ContactId] = @Contact_ContactId) AND ([Contact].[_rowVersion] = @_rowVersion))
SELECT @error = @@ERROR, @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
IF(@rowcount = 0)
BEGIN
    IF @tran = 1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR (50001, 16, 1, 'Contact_Delete')
    RETURN
END
IF @tran = 1 COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. The `delete` procedure generated for an entity also deletes the records of the *many to many* table.

A simple workaround is to create a `CFQL` method `DeleteById`:

```
DELETE(Id) WHERE Id = @Id
```

This method generates the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Meeting_DeleteById]
(
 @Id [uniqueidentifier]
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @deletedcount int
DELETE FROM [Meeting]
    WHERE ([Meeting].[Meeting_Id] = @Id)
SELECT @deletedcount = @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT @deletedcount 
RETURN
GO
```